# C++ Windows Forms application unhandled exception error when textbox empty

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

I'm building a temperature conversion application in Visual Studio for a C++ course. It's a Windows Forms application.

My problem is, when I run the application if I don't have anything entered into either the txtFahrenheit or txtCelsius2 textboxes I get the following error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

The application only works right now when a number is entered into both of the textboxes.

I was told to try and use this:

```
Double::TryParse()
```

but I'm brand new to C++ and can't figure out how to use it, even after checking the MSDN library.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, the language you're writing code in is not C++, it's C++/CLI. C++ code is almost always valid C++/CLI code, but because of differences in how things are done under the hood, they're not the same language. If you want C++, select "Win32 Console Application" or "MFC Application" when creating a new project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will check that the entry in your textbox is convertible to a number.

```
double val;
bool result = System::Double::TryParse(txtFahrenheit->Text,val);

if (result)
{
    //Converted successfully, you can use val
}
else
{
    //Error
}
```

Comment: no need to make result variable
if(System::Double::TryParse(txtFahrenheit->text,val)) would work too.